# Having trouble getting function to execute after panda preprocessing

Tags: python, pandas, function

I am doing some work with pandas that requires some preprocessing so that I can graph as intended. Right now I am looping through column names and deleting the ones I do not need. After I have done that I do a merge with another panda df so that I can execute the next function call. The code looks something like:

```
def makePlotFile(df, asg, dueDate, path, outputFile, gradesPath=None):
    print(gradesPath)
    vizData(df, asg, dueDate, path)
    vizAttempts(df, asg, dueDate, path)
    vizFirstAttempt(df, asg, dueDate, path)
    graph1 = path + "/output1.pdf"
    graph2 = path + "/output2.pdf"
    graph3 = path + "/output3.pdf"
    ready = False
    if gradesPath != None:
        print("Will include grade information")
        grades = pd.read_csv(gradesPath, error_bad_lines=False)
        for column_name, _ in grades.iteritems():
            if asg not in column_name:
                if column_name != 'Email':
                    del grades[column_name]
            if asg in column_name:
                grade = column_name
                ready = True
                print('GOT COLUMN NAME')
                #await asyncio.wait(grade)
        if ready:
            print('HIT IT')
            pd.merge(df, grades, on='Email')
            vizGradesFirstAttempt(df, asg, dueDate, path,grade)
            graph4 = path + "/output4.pdf"
            pdfs = [graph1, graph2, graph3, graph4]
            merger = PdfFileMerger()
            for pdf in pdfs:
                merger.append(pdf)
            merger.write(outputFile)
            merger.close()

    if gradesPath == None:
        print("No grade information given")
        pdfs = [graph1, graph2, graph3]
        merger = PdfFileMerger()

        for pdf in pdfs:
            merger.append(pdf)

        merger.write(outputFile)
        merger.close()
```

I have added in some print statements to help me debug. The statement "Will include grade information" prints but does not make it to the other print statements. I am not sure if it has to do with a synchronous issue or what. I would appreciate some guidance. I am assuming I am missing something small, but not sure what.

The function calls to:

````
vizAttempts(df, asg, dueDate, path)
vizFirstAttempt(df, asg, dueDate, path)```
All work as expected. They are functions that create graphs using my dataframe. I thne merge them into a single PDF. this is what the graph1, graph2, and graph3 help me with.
````

Comment: Only you have access to `path + "/output1.pdf"`. The obvious answer is none of those if statements evaluate to `True` but without sample data and a [mcve] this is mostly guesswork.

Comment: I said in my question that the if statement if gradesPath != None does execute since the print statement prints out, but the others inside of it do not which have nothing to do with the paths. I can even put a print statement inside the for loop and it works, but the ifs nested inside the for loop do not

Comment: That's one print statement, the others are all nested within their respective statements `gradesPath != None` might be True, but why does that say anything about `if ready`, which is required to get to `print('HIT IT')`???

Comment: The idea is that if I have a gradesPath I need to sort through the grades panda that I make and identify the wanted column which I will then merge into df. I use ready to identify that I have processed the information and I am ready to merge. I attempted this in order to make thing occur in a certain order. Without this statement, it will attempt to execute the vizGradesFirstAttempt(df, asg, dueDate, path,grade) statements but grade is not defined.